# (DrRacket) String manipulation problem creating student emails

Tags: racket

I am having trouble with finding the part of the string for the 1st name when the goose email length is less then 9

```
(check-expect( goose-mail "becky""anderson"12)"12abecky@uragoose.ca")
```

At Goose University, students are given a unique username based on their name and a special ID
number. The username starts with the special ID number, followed by the first letter of their last
name, and then followed by their first name. All of the usernames are restricted to a maximum of
9 letters, therefore it is often the case that only a portion of the first name is included. All of the
usernames are in lower case. The special ID number is a positive integer that is less than 1000. The
email address is the username with “@uragoose.ca" appended to it.
Write a Racket function goose-mail that consumes two non-empty strings first-name, last-name,
and a non-negative integer ID-num, where 0 ≤ ID-num ≤ 999 and produces the email address for the
student with the specified first and last names and ID number. The first name and last name are
provided in lower case.
>
 What I have so far is

```
(check-expect(1st-last-name-letter "pham")"p")
(define(1st-last-name-letter L)
  (substring L 0 1))

(check-expect(ID-num 12)"12")
(define (ID-num ID)
  (number->string ID))


(check-expect(user-name "andrew" "pham" 123)"123pandrew")

(define(user-name first-name last-name ID)

(string-append (string-append(ID-num ID)(1st-last-name-letter last-name))
first-name) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just need to check the length of the resulting username, and trim it to the required size if necessary:

```
(define (user-name first-name last-name ID)
  (let ((username (string-append (ID-num ID) (1st-last-name-letter last-name) first-name)))
    (if (<= (string-length username) 9)
        username
        (substring username 0 9))))
```

Comment: Hi, I've voted to undelete [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59993838/849891).

Comment: @WillNess thanks! that one looks like OP got his answer and doesn't want to share it :-|

Comment: I was hoping our two votes would be enough. I'll flag it for a mod to undelete it.