# How can I transform this code into Racket/ Scheme

Tags: java, list, scheme, racket, code-translation

This is the code I want translated into Racket:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> convert(int k, int n) {
        ArrayList<Integer> lst = new ArrayList<>();
        while (k / n != 0) {
            lst.add(k % n); 
            k = k/n;
        }
        lst.add(k % n);
        return lst; 
    }
```

e.g. in Racket the `(convert 23 2)` should return the binary of the decimal *23*, which is `(list 1 0 1 1 1)`.

This is what I got so far:

```lisp
(define (convert k n)
  (cond 
    [(> (/ k n) 0) (list(modulo k n))]
    [else  0] 
))
```

It works for the first element of the list.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Of course it only works for the first element, you're not looping _at all_. You need to use recursion to implement looping. Did you know that you must use `cons` to build lists in Scheme?

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that the `/` operator in Java performs integer division, so in Racket you'd have to use `quotient` to obtain the same effect.

This is a good opportunity to use a named `let` to implement the loop, as the result list needs to be accumulated in reverse. Other than that, the solution is pretty straightforward:

```
(define (convert k n)
  (let loop ((k k) (acc '()))
    (if (zero? (quotient k n))
        (cons (modulo k n) acc)
        (loop (quotient k n) (cons (modulo k n) acc)))))
```

For example:

```
(convert 23 2)
=> '(1 0 1 1 1)
```